# Why can't I use a resourcestring as a constant?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I've downloaded `embtvstools` (Embarcadero TVirtualShellTools) from: http://embtvstools.svn.sourceforge.net/

However when I create a new package, drop the .pas files *(and a missing `compilers.inc` from VirtualTreeView in)* and compile the lot, I get an error E2026, **why is this and how do I avoid/workaround this?**

```
resourcestring
    sAssociationChanged = 'Association Changed';
    sItemCreate = 'Item Create';
    sItemDelete = 'Item Delete';
    ....

const
  // Literal translations of TShellNotifyEvent type.  Useful when using the
  // OnShellNotify event to print out what event occurred.  VirtualShellUtilities.pas
  // has a helper function ShellNotifyEventToStr that uses these.
  VET_NOTIFY_EVENTS: array[0..19] of WideString = (
    sAssociationChanged,
    sAttributes,
    sItemCreate,
    .....
```

> [Pascal Error] IDEVirtualResources.pas(155): E2026 Constant expression expected
>   [Pascal Error] IDEVirtualResources.pas(156): E2026 Constant expression expected
>   [Pascal Error] IDEVirtualResources.pas(157): E2026 Constant expression expected

**Update**
Changing the `widestring` to a `string` stops the compiler complaining, (I suspect it will create some issue elsewhere because widestring <> string) I would like to keep the constant of type `widestring`.

Comment: The code is probably meant for D2009+ where resourcestrings are WideStrings.

Comment: For what it's worth, D2009 and D2010 do not complain about this. May have something to do with Unicode. WideStrings after all are Windows Managed UTF-16LE strings... And resourcestrings in pre-D2009 are AnsiStrings.

Comment: I have to say I find it surprising that you can even have a typed constant of `WideString`. Are they real `WideStrings` allocated at runtime with the COM allocator, or are they just pointers to null-terminated WideChar arrays?

Comment: If an AnsiString can hold the characters that you need then you don't need to worry about storing as AnsiString and then converting to WideString. The compiler will do that transparently for you.

Comment: @Uwe in D2009+ resourcestrings are System.string is the IDE insight is to be believed.

Comment: @Uwe It seems that IDE insight is not to be believed!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I never trust the IDE insight, I trust whatever code is thrown at it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Uwe points out in the comments, `resourcestring` in Unicode versions of Delphi is of type `WideString`. But you are using pre-Unicode Delphi and so `resourcestring` is simply `AnsiString`. This explains the compilation error.

How to proceed depends on what you are attempting to do. If you intend to translate these strings into different languages then you may be in a bind. If you are intending to do that then you would obviously be far better off with a Unicode version of Delphi.

So, since you are sticking with a pre-Unicode Delphi I guess you don't actually need to translate the strings. In which case just change the declaration of the `const` array from `WideString` to `string`. As it happens, this array is declared by this code but never once referred to.